# Return a string value from stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure to return the record counts in a number of other stored procedures.I have the following to create a string value:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_Prepare_Default_Page 
    @Status int,
    @CurrentUser int,
    @DisplayUser int,
    @OwnRecords BIT = 0,
    @array VARCHAR(MAX) = '' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dgActions INT = 0
    DECLARE @dgAllocByMe INT = 0
    DECLARE @dgCompliance INT = 0

     EXEC uSp_myTask_CurrentTasks @Status, @CurrentUser, @DisplayUser, @OwnRecords
     SET @dgActions = @@rowcount

     EXEC uSp_myTask_ComplianceProcess @Status, @CurrentUser, @DisplayUser, @OwnRecords
     SET @dgCompliance = @@rowcount
     SET @array = CAST(@dgActions AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(@dgAllocByMe AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(@dgCompliance AS VARCHAR(10))

     select @array AS tabDataCounts
END
GO
```

When this is executed within SQL Server Management Studio each of the executed stored procedures is displayed along with my string value.

When I execute the stored procedure in my ASP.Net application I only get the data from the first stored procedure.

Can anyone advise how to get just the string value?

Thanks

James

Comment: The `@array` variable should have the information you want.  Something is probably going wrong on the application side.

Comment: show your ASP.net code, it should be something like your dataset.Tables[0/1/2].

Answer (score 0):

That @array variable looks great. Everything's running fine. The SQL query fires, database operations completed. So where is the ouput?

In order to catch the data on the ASP.net side of things, you'll need to do a few things

1) Declare an output variable to catch the values that your sproc returns.

```
SQLParameter array = new SQLParameter();
array.ParameterName = "@array";
array.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
array.DBType = DbType.Text;
```

2) Ok, so now the `array` variable will catch the value. Now how does your query know about it? You have to add it to the parameters that are sent to the query.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("your command", "your connection");
command.Parameters.Add(array);
```

3) Ok, so now your command has access to the parameter and will jam `@array`'s value into the array variable. What about actually getting your C# code to access it?

```
string returnedValue = string.empty
returnedValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

These last 2 lines can be different dependent upon a number of factors. But assuming your `@array` value is a string and you're executing a non-query, this would work. Please ask if you have any issues with these lines.

Now, `returnedValue` will contain your output parameter.

4) What if you have multiple return values from your stored procedure?

```
command.Parameters["@array"].Value
command.Parameters["some other parameter"].Value
command.Parameters["another parameter"].Value
```

will give you access to the additional parameters after you've executed the command.

Comment: Thanks for that. I adapted your code for VB (shown below) but I get the following error on the ExecuteNonQuery:
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=String[0]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: Even better way: `new SqlParameter("@array", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);`

Comment: Then set the direction. Try that, let me know what comes of it.

Comment: The `-1` setting lets SQL Server knows it's `varchar(max)`